# Is there any tutorial or game engine to make games like Antrim Escape?

Tags: android

I've been searching for open source examples or tutorials on making games like the Antrim Escape but with no luck. Most of the open source examples I've found are mostly puzzle games like sudoku. I've heard about AndEngine, ORK and Unity but I don't know if they are any use in making games like the Antrim Escape (sorry, I'm a newbie to Android). It would be great if anyone could give me some directions or tutorial links on how to make puzzle games from scratch.  Any help is deeply appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well there is a good library as you might have the information of jMonkeyEngine 3... There is tutorials available for that... But the problem is the current Emulator doesn't support OpenGL ES 2... As the library is purely for OpenGL ES 2.0... So far what I know... But there is another framework like [Libgdx](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/) it is written by the writer of the book Beginning Android Games from apress publication. And there is a good quick tutorial on game development in android for both 2d and 3d in [Obivam](http://obviam.net)